# Python 2.4 installer hangs on Windows 8

Tags: python, installation

For the sake of using an old Python extension, I need to use Python 2.4.  Now trying to install it on an Acer laptop running Windows 8.1 64 bit, the installer hangs as it opens the second screen, "Select Destination Directory". Reliably.

To get around this I tried command line strategies such as

msiexec /i python-2.4.4.msi TARGETDIR=c:\python24

but no such command avoids it displaying the troubling screen.

Has anyone seen this problem? Any fix?

Comment: You can probably build it yourself from source, or use a tool like `pipenv` that can install it for you, parallel to other python installations.

Comment: … although you may need to build it from source using the appropriate older MSVC compiler, or it may not work with the extension.